# Java API for OpenText eDocs/Hummingbird

Tags: opentext

Does anyone know if there is a java API provided for OpenText eDocs (formerly Hummingbird DM)?

Our experience in using it in our webapp is limited to client-side access using ActiveX, we'd like to know if there's a way to access the API on the server side using Java

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't use java myself. But their API is COM/DCOM based so if you could manage to interface with that (http://j-interop.org/ looks promising). You're set.